# Create New Log File Once it reaches the Size Specified in MFC (VC++ )?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a Log file by name "NDSLog" now i wanted that if NDSLog file exceeds its limit a new file should create by name NDSLog1 and so on...Currently i am able to create NDSLog file and when it exceeds it limit, I close that exisiting file & open a new file .

I want to know i can increment NDSLog to NDSLog1 and so on when it reaches that Limit ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

I am using WritetoLog method for this.

```
long CNDSLog::WriteLogData(char *logData, long lDataSize)
    {

if (m_File == NULL)
{
    GetFileName();
    OpenNewFile();
}
else
{
    long lFileSize = GetFileSize(m_sFileName);
    if (lFileSize > m_lFileSize)
    {
        CloseNewFile(); 
        GetFileName();
        OpenNewFile();
    }
}

WriteData(logData);

return ERR_NONE;
```

}

```
long CNDSLog::GetFileName()
{
    char ctemp[300];
int lLen = sprintf(ctemp,"%s",m_sFName.data());

if (lLen > 0)
{       
    if (m_sFileName != NULL)
    {
        delete [] m_sFileName;
        m_sFileName = NULL;
    }

    m_sFileName = new char[lLen + 1];
    memset(m_sFileName,0,lLen + 1);
    memcpy(m_sFileName,ctemp,lLen);
}

return ERR_NONE;
```

};

```
long CNDSLog::OpenNewFile()
{
    if (m_sFileName != NULL)
    {
        char strPathName[_MAX_PATH];
        ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, strPathName, _MAX_PATH);      

    // The following code will allow you to get the path.
    CString newPath(strPathName);
    int iPos = newPath.ReverseFind('\\');

    if (iPos != -1)
    newPath = newPath.Left(iPos+1);     
    newPath += "NDSLog\\" ;


    if (GetFileAttributes(newPath) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    {
      CreateDirectory(newPath,NULL);
    }   
    newPath +=  m_sFileName;        

    m_File = fopen(newPath,"at");
}
return ERR_NONE;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

An esay way is to have a counter in your WriteLogData () function int nCounter passing it to GetFileName(). When you are vreating the filename you could add the counter like that:

```
sprintf(ctemp,"%s_%d",m_sFName.data(), nCounter);
```

Now you have your 1, 2, ...

Now your WriteLogData () should be like that:

```
long CNDSLog::WriteLogData(char *logData, long lDataSize)
    {

in nCounter = 1; // or whatever
if (m_File == NULL)
{
    GetFileName(nCounter);
    OpenNewFile();
}
else
{
    long lFileSize = GetFileSize(m_sFileName);
    if (lFileSize > m_lFileSize)
    {
        nCounter++;
        CloseNewFile(); 
        GetFileName(nCounter);
        OpenNewFile();
    }
}

WriteData(logData);

return ERR_NONE;
```

Comment: But how it feel create a ew file with name NDSLog1 and so on...it just increment the counter ...

Comment: No because you updated the signatyure for GrtFileName() function as well, it takes the counter as a parameter and use it to create the actual file name.

Comment: No, it is not taking that updated filename and creating a new one , for creating a new file something like Createfile or some other function has to be used.how to that part ? That part is missing here i guess.